# Swift: Detect and Cancel Another App's Notification

Tags: swift, notifications, intercept

On Android, I have a NotificationListenerService that I can use in my third party app to intercept push notifications from a service's official app, cancel it, and post my own from my app's service (basically shadowing a push notification and making my own so I don't have to constantly poll the service's API).

Is there anything similar on iOS? I have been searching and cannot find documentation of anything that lets me capture another app's posted notification events, but I know it is possible to view their content as some apps (like the Samsung Watch's app) can forward notifications to other displays.

Comment: That sounds like a security bug - you should not be able to remove other app's notifications.

Comment: @Cristik it is a bit of a workaround but is possible using accessibility options or the new Notification library in api 19+ in Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no such feature on iOS. Apple goes to great lengths to prevent 3rd party apps from altering the behavior of the system or of other apps.

Comment: Didn't think there was going to be, thanks for the answer. Any idea of how Samsung does notification mirroring to their watches from iOS, though? Just curious about how they are able to see this

Comment: You're probably looking for this: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @PeejWeej, ok that's the docs of the APNS. However, the OP was asking specifically about intercepting push notifications targeted to a different app, which is not possible on iOS (excluding jailbroken devices, where all bets are off.)

Comment: @DuncanC I was answering "Any idea of how Samsung does notification mirroring to their watches from iOS" not the original question.

Comment: Recently I noticed an application I have on my device sends its own notification when it detects a VERY SPECIFIC push notification from an completely different app. I am so confused on how they are doing it, I am trying to find the answer to this mystery.